# VB.Net - Get the byte size of type

Tags: vb.net, .net-3.5

How can I get the byte size of a type ? For exemple, the size of a `Double` is 8, but how can I get this value programmatically ?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [Marshal.SizeOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5s4920fa%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)-Method, which will return the size in bytes.

You can use it like that:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(GetType(Double))
```